# glGetTexImage unexpected results

Tags: c, opengl

I try to read texture data from GPU to save it in an image file using `glGetTexImage`
But when I open the image I get a mix of pixel instead of my expected result.

```
char buffer[size.x * size.y]; // simple one channel buffer
// Copy source to local buffer
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, source);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_ALPHA, buffer);
saveImage("before.pgm", buffer, size.x, size.y);
```

During the texture creation I do this:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

// Define texture characteristics with no data. It will be filled later
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, size.x, size.y, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

/* We require 1 byte alignment when uploading or downloading texture data */
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've swapped the *format* and *type* argument in the call to [`glGetTexImage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml). It has to be:

<s>`glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_ALPHA, buffer);`</s>

```c
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

Since the *format* and the *type* are not accepted values, this will cause an `INVALID_ENUM` error.

Comment: Oh boy... It was so stupid.. Another reason to put some glGetError inside of the code !

Comment: @ErwanDaniel You're welcome. Note, since OpenGL 4.3 it is possible to generate [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output). You can get a synchron callback, whenever an error occurs. See the [PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/t8cL9hEb)

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm stuck in OpenGL 2.1 due to hardware limitation on the project. But it's good to know, thanks !